# Inserir dados na BD e de seguida mudar de tab

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Como é que posso avançar de tab após fazer a inserção de dados na minha base de dados?

```
    private void botaoAvancarTab1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    String inserirArtigo = "";
    String nome = txtNome.getText();
    String descricao = txtDescricao.getText();
    String designacaoComercial = txtDesignacaoComercial.getText();
    String stock = txtStockAtual.getText();
    String ativo = "";
    if (jCheckBoxAtivo.isSelected()) {
        ativo = "1";
    } else {
        ativo = "0";
    }

    inserirArtigo = "insert into artigo (Nome, Descricao, Designacao_Comercial, Ativo,Stock) "
            + "values ('" + nome + "','" + descricao + "','" + designacaoComercial + "','" + ativo + "','" + stock + "')";

    try {
        int done = stmt.executeUpdate(inserirArtigo);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConfArtigo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("Dados inseridos com sucesso!!");
    jTabConfArtigo.setEnabledAt(1, true);
    jTabConfArtigo.setSelectedIndex(1);
}
```

O programa executa até ao `System.out.println("Dados inseridos com sucesso")` mas não muda para a `tab` seguinte, alguém sabe o porquê ?

Comment: Acredito que estas utilizando um `JTabbedPane`,certo? O que faz o `initCOmponents()` aí?

Comment: Você poderia postar o código que monta a janela? Se não puder, ao menos mostre-nos como a `jTabConfArtigo` é criada, por favor.